# How can I grant & revoke specific rights from Postgresql users?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-grant

I have been tasked to host HTML & PHP files of a website on one virtual machine and to set up a Postgresql database on another virtual machine.

I recently installed Postgresql and have been using the official Postgresql Documentation to learn how to create databases, create user and grant & revoke rights.

After having created a database named ***mfc_dst***, I was ordered to create 4 differents users and this is where I have a problem :

-The first user has to be named admin and must be the only other user than the pre-existing user named ***postgres*** to have unlimited rights.

-The second (named **cfc**) and third user (named **sec**) must only have the ***SELECT*** and ***UPDATE*** privileges on all tables of the ***mfc_dst*** database.

-And the fourth/last user (named **prof**) must only be able to view a table named **devoir** from the database named ***mfc_dst***.

To accomplish this, I used 2 different scripts :

```
CREATEandGRANT.sql

REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO cfc;
REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO sec;
REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO prof;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mfc_dst TO admin;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mfc_dst TO cfc;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mfc_dst TO sec;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mfc_dst TO prof;

GRANT SELECT,UPDATE
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
TO cfc;

GRANT SELECT,UPDATE
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
TO sec;

GRANT SELECT ON devoir TO prof;
```

and this other one :

```
REVOKE.sql

REVOKE ALL ON TABLE professeur FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE reserver FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE salle FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE semaine FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE surveiller FROM PUBLIC;
```

Thanks to these 2 scripts, I was able to prevent the user named prof from seeing other tables, but the problem I have is that the users named cfc,sec and prof are still all three able to create tables and to ***drop*** them.

Is it possible to know how to prevent them from doing this and if possible, in the future, prevent newly created users from having such rights/privileges ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

All Postgres users implicitly are also automatically members of the `public` role, which grants them all permissions on the `public` schema.  You can remove permissions from the `public` role with

```
revoke all on database mfc_dst from public;
revoke all on schema public from public;
```

Additionally, consider defining a new schema for your data tables, so that you can issue `grant` statements without having to deal further with the `public` role.  If you do this, you can also set the search path to include your custom schema and to exclude the `public` schema.

Also, you might want to create a group role for the `cfc` and `sec` users and assign permissions to that role, rather than to the users individually.  This will make future maintenance easier.